# swt section disable collapse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

How can i disable collapse for section element. Client element should be enabled. I have one option, but it looks not good.

```
timeSettingsSection.addExpansionListener(new IExpansionListener() {

        @Override
        public void expansionStateChanging(ExpansionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void expansionStateChanged(ExpansionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getState()) {
                timeSettingsSection.setExpanded(true);
                return;
            }
            if (stopSection.isExpanded())
                stopSection.setExpanded(false);
            if (cabinTypeSection.isExpanded())
                cabinTypeSection.setExpanded(false);
            if (airlinesSection.isExpanded())
                airlinesSection.setExpanded(false);
            sectionExpanded();
            useDepartTime.setFocus();
        }
    });
```

Yes it is org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.section

```
    timeSettingsSection = getToolkit().createSection(mainGroup, Section.LEFT_TEXT_CLIENT_ALIGNMENT | Section.TWISTIE);
    timeSettingsSection.setText("Time");
    GridUtils.fillHorz(timeSettingsSection);

    Composite group = getToolkit().createComposite(timeSettingsSection, SWT.NONE);
    GridUtils.gridLayoutObj(group).numColumns(3).noMargins();
    getToolkit().paintBordersFor(group);
    timeSettingsSection.setClient(group);
```

Comment: What kind of widget/control are you using? Please post more code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section` class.

If you create the section without specifying the `TWISTIE` or `TREE_NODE` styles then the section will not be collapsable.

Comment: Actually i have 4 Section and i need that only one of them are expanded but at any time 1 section should be expanded .

Comment: Well that is not what you actually asked.